# How to convert an Arraylist(object) to an Arraylist(String) so I can use the .add method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a snippet of code that allows me to read through a text file and then returns that said list. However, when I try to add the next line of my text file there is an error that constantly switches my .add to an .addAll and then tries to revert back to .add. I assume this is because my ArrayList is not a string, so how would I convert my ArrayList so it's contents can be read and added?

```
private ArrayList<Patron> patronList = new ArrayList<Patron>();
```

---

```
private ArrayList<Patron> readPatrons(String filename) {
        ArrayList<Patron> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner s = null;
        File infile = new File(filename);
        try{
            s = new Scanner(infile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(s.hasNext())
            lines.add(s.next()); // Error here. 
        return lines;
```

Comment: Simply define it as `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: You should probably try to convert the string to a `Patron`, judging from how your method is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a Patron object and a constructor in it to be better...for example

```
public class Patron{
   String name;
    public patron(String name){
      this.name=name;
  }
}
```

then while taking input you can do something like this

```
String S=s.next();
lines.add(new Patron(S));//or you can directly do lnes.add(new Patron(scan.next()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code   `lines.add(s.next());`
lines is an arraylist of Patron object, so you can add Patron object in it.

s.next() is going to give you a string. so that's why an error.

Create a Patron object and then add to lines

Answer (score 0):

```
s.next()
```

returns a String, not a Patron. If your Patron class had a constructor that takes a String to create a Patron instance you would have to do something like

```
lines.add(new Patron(s.next()));
```